# last-child selector not properly getting set if there are inner divs

Tags: css, css-selectors

I created a simplified version of my problem at http://jsfiddle.net/ahvru/

I want the very last `item` `class` within the `parent` class to be a different color. Instead, it will set that last `item` class of each inner `div`, not the actually `parent class`.

The expected result should be that `item4` is the only blue div not matter how many inner divs I have

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is right behavior, [read docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-child)

You would have to do something like this

```
.parent .inner2 .item:last-child{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

But that propably is`t  soulution you whant.

I don`t se any other way than add some class via JavaScript or change your html structure to use :last-child properly

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
.parent div:last-child .item:last-child{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using "last-of-type" in your css selector if you're using css3.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-of-type.asp

Answer (score 0):

Without actually counting the number of `.item` children than `.parent` has, I'm afraid you're going to be out of luck. However, for this scenario specifically, it just so happens that this works:

```
.parent .item:not(:first-child) {
    background-color:red;
}
.item:last-of-type {
    height:30px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```